# How to view individual Heroku dyno

Tags: heroku

I'd like to know things like cpu and memory usage on a per-machine basis. Is it possible to obtain information like this on individual dynos in Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics) feature, which will regularly log to your app the CPU and memory usage.

That data will then be available through the `heroku logs` command.

You can also use the [Heroku Exec](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-exec) feature to open an SSH instance into the running dyno.